# I've changed the name of the class yet the previous name is also remembered

Tags: ruby

I created a file with a class `Contact`. I loaded that file in irb or pry session. I was able to access `Contact`.

I then changed `Contact` to `Vendor` in the file, and then reloaded the file while still running the irb or pry session. I can now access both the old `Contact` and the new `Vendor` classes.

If I re-start an irb or pry session and load the same file, this time, only `Vendor` is accessible. Is this a known glitch?

Answer (score 1):

Just as the way other programs work, Ruby interpreter reads contents into Random Access Memory (RAM), and executes based on what is in the RAM. Once you load a file, it does not matter what change you make to the file. From your first load, you have `Contract` in the RAM. Reloading the same file with different content does not erase anything from the RAM as long as the process is still running.

Comment: Thank you, I can appreciate that. So loading the .rb file is simply accepting another line of code to remember when I change the .rb file. When I exit irb or pry all lines of code are forgotten. Check.